# What is the best way to host a MicroService .net core web api in Docker?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, microservices

I have several micro services that I would like to dockerized them. Is it better to build them in a self-hosted console application or build asp.net web application?

Which one is faster?

My MicroServices are only simple Web Api.

Comment: ASP.NET Core **IS** a self-hosted console application

Comment: yes, it is. but my question is what is the best way to host that into docker. self host as a console app or web application in iis?

Comment: Unless you expect 10000+ requests per second on a single machine, performance differences won't matter. Choose which one works better with your workflow and deployment strategies. Most performance bottlenecks are not created by the iis, docker or nginx, they are by bad application architecture and code

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna give you my experience on this, not necessarily a 'complete answer':

If you create a .NET Core WEB API in Visual Studio and 'Add Docker support', you can directly deploy them to regular AppServices (specify 'Linux' as the operating system when you CREATE the AppService).

The Visual Studio wizard will automatically setup the container registry for your images, and configure the appservice to deploy whenever there's a new tag for your image.

I've also migrated this same Web API to deploy to a Windows AppService without docker, we didn't need to change any of the code, just deploy it without docker as a regular web app.

Which means if you build this as a .NET CORE 2 Web API you can deploy the same code to either a Linux Appservice using Docker or to a regular Appservice.

If you're planning to use anything different than AppServices tho, you might want to check Container services or Service Fabric, which IIRC is more expensive (would make sense if you need to scale this massively)